# Why doesn't my for loop execute within my getJSON request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure if it's possibly due to asynch execution. My JavaScript knowledge is pretty limited  so I can't identify why doesn't doesn't work, but on another webpage the exact same structure runs. I have also ensured that there is data found by the get request.

```
$.getJSON(products_url, function(data) {
//    console.log(data) //  has length 2
    for (var i=0; i <= data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i]);
    }
});
```

console.log(data) returns:

```
{data: Array(2)}
data: Array(2)
0: {desc: "Apples are delicious", images: "https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/2b4a8c7c-941f-457…809c.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF"}
1: {desc: "Oranges are delicious", images: ""}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

### Update: Solution

For anyone else who might come across this question, Vlaz answer highlighted my error. Data is an object returned by the request. To access the data itself, data.data is required. So, the correct code looks like:

```
$.getJSON(products_url, function(data) {
//    console.log(data);
    for (var i=0; i <= data.data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data.data[i]);
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you post `data`?

Comment: Do you have any error in the JS console ? (F12)

Comment: what is the type of data? array or JSON object?

Comment: Data is the callback right?
The only errors I have are related to an Unexpected console statement and that $. is undefined. However, I know these are working since I can see on my backend that the request is succeeding and that I can log data in the function before the for loop

Comment: Actually, console is stating it's a data array

Comment: It means that `data` is an *object* that has a *property* called `data` and that thing is an array. So, you need `data.data.length`

Comment: also, try to remove "=" from the length of  for loop,

Comment: Thanks Vlaz! Your solution worked. I didn't notice the nesting.